# How to delete commands from iTerm2's command history (Cmd+Shift+;)

Tags: macos, bash, shell, iterm2

I like the iTerm2's Command History feature, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>, to quickly find a command from the history.

But there are some commands that I want to remove from the list, I already run command like `sed -i "" '/searchstring/d' "$HISTFILE"` to delete them from bash history file.

But when I run <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>, these commands still show, where iTerm2 store them, how can I update and delete some commands from it?

Answer (score 1):

There might be an easier solution, but here's what I found so far:

- run `sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/iTerm2/ShellHistory.sqlite`
- identify the line you want to delete with `select * from ZCOMMANDHISTORYENTRY;`
- delete it with `delete from ZCOMMANDHISTORYENTRY where Z_PK = <id of entry, in first column>`
- restart iTerm

Or if you want to delete all commands that contain a given string:

```
delete from ZCOMMANDHISTORYENTRY where ZCOMMAND like '%example%';
```

Comment: I don't see the table in sqlite3: 

```
% sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/iTerm2/ShellHistory.sqlite
SQLite version 3.37.0 2021-12-09 01:34:53
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> select * from ZCOMMANDHISTORYENTRY;
Error: in prepare, no such table: ZCOMMANDHISTORYENTRY (1)
sqlite>
```

Comment: @VikasGoel maybe you are running another version of iTerm than mine, and the table names changed. Perhaps you can use sqlite syntax to get a list of tables, and find the corresponding one

Comment: I am using iterm2 version - 3.4.14 and sqlite version 3.37.0 2021-12-09 01:34:53.